# 'garray' object has no attribute 'size' using nolearn-DBN classifier

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-nolearn

I am working on [openface](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/). Openface has [unknown classification python cod](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/evaluation/lfw-classification-unknown.py)e.

I am testing `lfw-classification-unknown.py's` train part.
It has training using

```
nolearn-DBN classifier
```

I installed `nolearn version 0.5`.
`DBN classifier` has a function call to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py` and 
I have error as

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py", line 738, in as_numpy_array
    if self.size==0: return numpy.zeros(self.shape, dtype)
AttributeError: 'garray' object has no attribute 'size'
```

How can I fix the error?

The whole errors are

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1314, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 1233, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 400, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "evaluation/lfw-classification-unknown.py", line 519, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "evaluation/lfw-classification-unknown.py", line 130, in train
    clf.fit(embeddings, labelsNum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nolearn/dbn.py", line 409, in fit
    self.use_dropout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdbn/dbn.py", line 202, in fineTune
    err, outMB = step(inpMB, targMB, self.learnRates, self.momentum, self.L2Costs, useDropout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdbn/dbn.py", line 296, in stepNesterov
    targetBatch = targetBatch if isinstance(targetBatch, gnp.garray) else gnp.garray(targetBatch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py", line 735, in __new__
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwarg): return object.__new__(cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 53, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_return(frame, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 88, in dispatch_return
    self.user_return(frame, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 190, in user_return
    self.interaction(frame, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 209, in interaction
    self.print_stack_entry(self.stack[self.curindex])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 900, in print_stack_entry
    prompt_prefix)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 381, in format_stack_entry
    s = s + repr.repr(rv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/repr.py", line 24, in repr
    return self.repr1(x, self.maxlevel)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/repr.py", line 34, in repr1
    s = __builtin__.repr(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py", line 1133, in __repr__
    def __repr__(self): return self.as_numpy_array().__repr__().replace('array(', 'garray(').replace('\n', '\n ').replace(', dtype=float32', '').replace(', dtype=float64', '') # 64 happens for empty arrays
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py", line 738, in as_numpy_array
    if self.size==0: return numpy.zeros(self.shape, dtype)
AttributeError: 'garray' object has no attribute 'size'
> Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py(738)as_numpy_array()
-> if self.size==0: return numpy.zeros(self.shape, dtype)
```

EDIT:
If not in Debug mode, the error is as follow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluation/lfw-classification-unknown.py", line 519, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "evaluation/lfw-classification-unknown.py", line 130, in train
    clf.fit(embeddings, labelsNum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nolearn/dbn.py", line 407, in fit
    self.use_dropout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdbn/dbn.py", line 202, in fineTune
    err, outMB = step(inpMB, targMB, self.learnRates, self.momentum, self.L2Costs, useDropout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdbn/dbn.py", line 303, in stepNesterov
    errSignals, outputActs, error = self.fpropBprop(inputBatch, targetBatch, useDropout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdbn/dbn.py", line 262, in fpropBprop
    outputErrSignal = -self.outputActFunct.dErrordNetInput(targetBatch, self.state[-1], outputActs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdbn/activationFunctions.py", line 138, in dErrordNetInput
    return acts - targets
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py", line 965, in __sub__
    else: return self + -as_garray(other) # if i need to broadcast, making use of the row add and col add methods is probably faster
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py", line 926, in __add__
    def __add__(self, other): return _check_number_types(self._broadcastable_op(as_garray_or_scalar(other), 'add'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py", line 614, in _broadcastable_op
    if reduce(operator.or_, ( other.shape[i] not in (1, self.shape[i]) for i in range(self.ndim)), False): raise ValueError('shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape')
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to give a good answer. At the very least, you need to post the complete error message, including the whole stack trace (instead of just the last part). Really, you need to add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (eg some code that will raise the same error) to your question, or else I don't think anyone is going to be able to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You haven't posted any actual code, so it's literally impossible to know exactly what your problem is.</s>

## Edit

From your stack trace, it's clear that the problem you're having is due to `pdb` trying to grab and print the value of a `garray` immediately after `garray.__new__` is called. This is before `__init__` is called, so the `.size` attribute doesn't exist yet.

It doesn't seem like the redefinition of `__new__` is even necessary in the `gnumpy.garray` code, so you might be able to fix your problem by just opening up `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnumpy.py` and then commenting out line 735 (ie the line with the definition of `__new__`).

Even simpler, what happens when you just run the script without using `pdb` (eg `python lfw-classification-unknown.py`)? It seems like this specific error would vanish. On the other hand, you were presumably using the debugger for an actual reason in the first place. Were you originally getting a different error? In that case, this is an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), and you should probably just post a new question asking about the original error.

Unfortunately, `gnumpy.garray` requires an actual NVidia GPU to run, which I don't have, so I can't test these solutions myself directly.

## The general problem

That being said, it seems that somehow a `garray` object is being created without it's `.size` attribute being set. This could be due a bug in your own code, or in any of 4 different packages (`openface` plus 3 dependencies). Here's a very general overview of how that might be happening.

[`openface`](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface) has a dependency on [`nolearn`](https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn), which has a dependency on [`gbdn`](https://github.com/dnouri/gdbn), which has a dependency on [`gnumpy`](https://github.com/dnouri/gnumpy). In detail:

- The `openface` code you link to has [a dependency](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/evaluation/lfw-classification-unknown.py#L51)  on [the `nolearn.dbn.DBN` class](https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/blob/master/nolearn/dbn.py#L18).
- `nolearn.dbn.DBN` [has a dependency](https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/blob/master/nolearn/dbn.py#L5) on [the `gdbn.dbn.buldDBN` function](https://github.com/dnouri/gdbn/blob/master/gdbn/dbn.py#L77), and through it the [`gdbn.dbn.DBN` class](https://github.com/dnouri/gdbn/blob/master/gdbn/dbn.py#L103).
- Both `gdbn.dbn.buldDBN` and `gdbn.dbn.DBN` have code that creates arrays of [class `gnumpy.garray`](https://github.com/dnouri/gnumpy/blob/master/gnumpy.py#L558)

So, presumably, something is getting screwed up with the creation of one of the `garrays`'s in `buildDBN` or `DBN`. The `.size` attribute only gets set when [the `gnumpy.garray._set_shape_info` method](https://github.com/dnouri/gnumpy/blob/master/gnumpy.py#L566) is called. A cursory look over the implementation of `garray` doesn't reveal any obvious way in which `_set_shape_info` can fail to be called during initialization. However, one thing that does jump out is that there's at least a dozen different code paths by which initialization of a `garray` may occur. It wouldn't exactly be surprising if there's an edge case that slips past without calling `_set_shape_info`.

Comment: I am using this code `https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/evaluation/lfw-classification-unknown.py`. Not my own code. When you do training with this command, mentioned in this link `https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/pull/171`, I have such error training with `clfChoice == 'DBN':`

Comment: You need to add these details to your original question. If you're using their `lfw-classification-unknown.py` script, include the exact command line that you're running the script with.

Comment: I have added the whole error stack. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I posted an edit addressing the info in your complete stack trace. It's clear that the `pdb` debugger itself is causing your specific issue. What happens when you run the script without the debugger?

Comment: If I run not in Debug mode, the error is different. The error is shape mismatch. I have updated in Edit.

Comment: You do have an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Your actual problem has nothing to do with the question you asked. Instead of making this question an even more confusing mess, you should just ask a new question. Otherwise, it'll be too confusing for anyone who has a similar problem to find/read through.